# Split algorithm in two slides with beamer

Tags: beamer, algorithms, presentations, algorithmic, slideshow

I am following this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141655/splitting-algorithm-across-multiple-slides), but no luck as you can see:

[image]

The frame is being split into two slides, but the first slide is left empty! How to fix this?

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\def\RR{{\mathbb R}}
\def\Ss{{\mathbb S}}
\def\EE{{\mathbb E}}
\def\Pr{{\mathrm Pr}}
\def\dd{{\mathrm d}}
\def\ee{{\mathrm e}}
\def\MM{{\mathcal M}}
\def\sign{{\mathrm sign}}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\newcommand{\algorithmicinput}{\textbf{input}}
\newcommand{\INPUT}{\item[\algorithmicinput]}
\newcommand{\algorithmicoutput}{\textbf{output}}
\newcommand{\OUTPUT}{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Search}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Dolphinn: Query Algorithm}
    \label{DolphinnQuery}
    \begin{algorithmic}
    \INPUT{Metric $(\MM, d_{\MM})$, LSH family $F$, data set $P \subset \MM$, parameter $d'$, integer StopSearch, query $q$. (We assume that this algorithm has access to the ANN data structure created in Algorithm \ref{DolphinnPrep})}
    \OUTPUT{Point $p \in P$ or "no"}
    %\STATE{Compute $f(q)=(f_1(h_1(q)), f_2(h_2(q)), \ldots, f_{d'}(h_{d'}(q)))$ as folows:}
    \FOR{$i = 1$ to $d'$}
        \IF{$f_i(h_i(q))$ is not defined in Algorithm \ref{DolphinnPrep}}
            \STATE{Flip a fair coin and assign the result to $f_i(h_i(q))$.}
        \ELSE
            \STATE{Compute $f_i(h_i(q))$.}
        \ENDIF
    \ENDFOR

    \STATE{i=0}
    \FOR{\textbf{each} $x$ in $f(P)$ s.t. $\|x-f(q)\|_1\leq  0.5 \cdot d' \cdot (1-p_1)$ }
    \FOR{\textbf{each} point $p$ inside the bucket with key $x$}
    \IF{$d_{\MM}(p,q)\leq c\cdot r$}
        \STATE \textbf{return} $p$.
         \ENDIF
      \STATE{$i\gets i+1$}
     \IF{$i>StopSearch$}
        \STATE \textbf{return} "no". 
       \ENDIF

    \ENDFOR
    \ENDFOR
    \STATE{\textbf{return} "no"}

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: try removing the "algorithm" environment?

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. However even after adding the obviously missing documentclass etc. I cannot compile your code due to many `Undefined control sequence.` errors. Can you make a compilable MWE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May something like this do the job?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\def\RR{{\mathbb R}}
\def\Ss{{\mathbb S}}
\def\EE{{\mathbb E}}
\def\Pr{{\mathrm Pr}}
\def\dd{{\mathrm d}}
\def\ee{{\mathrm e}}
\def\MM{{\mathcal M}}
\def\sign{{\mathrm sign}}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\newcommand{\algorithmicinput}{\textbf{input}}
\newcommand{\INPUT}{\item[\algorithmicinput]}
\newcommand{\algorithmicoutput}{\textbf{output}}
\newcommand{\OUTPUT}{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}


\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Search}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
\captionof{algorithm}{Dolphinn: Query Algorithm}%
\vspace*{-0.5cm}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}%
\vspace*{-0.5cm}
%\begin{algorithm}[H]
%    \caption{Dolphinn: Query Algorithm}
    \label{DolphinnQuery}
    \begin{algorithmic}
    \INPUT{Metric $(\MM, d_{\MM})$, LSH family $F$, data set $P \subset \MM$, parameter $d'$, integer StopSearch, query $q$. (We assume that this algorithm has access to the ANN data structure created in Algorithm \ref{DolphinnPrep})}
    \OUTPUT{Point $p \in P$ or "no"}
    %\STATE{Compute $f(q)=(f_1(h_1(q)), f_2(h_2(q)), \ldots, f_{d'}(h_{d'}(q)))$ as folows:}
    \FOR{$i = 1$ to $d'$}
        \IF{$f_i(h_i(q))$ is not defined in Algorithm \ref{DolphinnPrep}}
            \STATE{Flip a fair coin and assign the result to $f_i(h_i(q))$.}
        \ELSE
            \STATE{Compute $f_i(h_i(q))$.}
        \ENDIF
    \ENDFOR

    \STATE{i=0}
    \FOR{\textbf{each} $x$ in $f(P)$ s.t. $\|x-f(q)\|_1\leq  0.5 \cdot d' \cdot (1-p_1)$ }
    \FOR{\textbf{each} point $p$ inside the bucket with key $x$}
    \IF{$d_{\MM}(p,q)\leq c\cdot r$}
        \STATE \textbf{return} $p$.
         \ENDIF
      \STATE{$i\gets i+1$}
     \IF{$i>StopSearch$}
        \STATE \textbf{return} "no". 
       \ENDIF

    \ENDFOR
    \ENDFOR
    \STATE{\textbf{return} "no"}

\end{algorithmic}
%\end{algorithm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting `Undefined control sequence.
<inserted text> ...\textwidth }{0.5pt} \captionof 
                                                  {algorithm}{Dolphinn: Quer...
l.184 \end{frame}`, any idea?

Comment: Did you `\usepackage{caption}`?

Comment: No, that was it! =)